# after login handling webpages through php curl program

Tags: php, curl

I'm not able to post values to field and process further steps to download a file. Could anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

```
    extract($_POST);  
      $url=header("Location: http://gis.lntecc.com/bwssblnt/Scada.aspx?   field1=Kathriguppe%2cSW2DM0402%2c235505H073%2c450");
   $fields =array(
            "TextBoxFromDate" => urlencode("2014-10-01"),
            "TextBoxToDate" =>  urlencode("2014-10-09")  
           );

    foreach($fields as $key => $value) 

    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';

    rtrim($fields, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
    curl_close($ch);
```

Where did I make a mistake since I'm not able to post values to the field?

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove that huge space in your URL:

```
 $url=header("Location: http://gis.lntecc.com/bwssblnt/Scada.aspx?   field1=Kathriguppe%2cSW2DM0402%2c235505H073%2c450");
```

Becomes:

```
 $url=header("Location: http://gis.lntecc.com/bwssblnt/Scada.aspx?field1=Kathriguppe%2cSW2DM0402%2c235505H073%2c450");
```